# Telerik RadGrid opening an extra popup edit form when pressing "enter" from a popup form for inserting

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I have a radgrid that uses the popup edit mode with a custom edit template.  The edit form upon pressing the enter key will insert a new item into the grid.  I go in and add an item.  This successfully inserts.  Then I go to add a second item:  The popup form appears.  I enter in my data and press the "enter" key to insert the item.  This time, instead of inserting the item, my edit form will clear out the data I entered and open another popup edit form to allow editing of my previously inserted item (from the first time).  I now have 2 popups (1 for inserting, 1 for updating).

If I click the insert button instead of pressing "enter", then everything works ok.  From what I can guess is that it is thinking that I'm pressing the enter on a selected row on the grid.  How do I prevent it from triggering the "edit" event while I'm trying to insert?

Thanks

Comment: Ever figure this one out? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a panel to the edit template and set the DefaultButton to your Insert button.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlEditor" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnUpdateItem">
```